Find an open interval about $0$ on which $|\sqrt{1+x}-1|<0.1$ holds
Find an open interval about $x_0$ on which the inequality
$$ | f(x) - L | < \epsilon $$ holds.
Where $$ f(x) = \sqrt{x+1}, x_0 = 0, \epsilon = 0.1, L = 1$$
Answer of above problem is $(-0.19,0.21), \delta = 0.19$. But I have no idea how to obtain this result. Please help me.

Hint: try computing $f(-0.19)$ and $f(0.21)$. This might help you reverse-engineer the answer.

How did the assumption come about computing the values ​​of f(-0.19) and f(0.21) when the answer is not known?

Sorry, I should have been more clear. I'm suggesting that computing those values $f(-0.19)$ and $f(0.21)$ will make it clear how this answer was arrived at in the first place, i.e. what the process was that arrived at the numbers $-0.19$ and $0.21$ in the first place. In particular, I was hoping you'd see that $f(-0.19) = L - \varepsilon$, and $f(0.21) = L + \varepsilon$, and that whoever wrote the solution, simply solved $f(x) = L-\varepsilon$ and $f(x) = L + \varepsilon$, and put them into an interval. This only works because $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing.

For $x\ge0$,
$$\sqrt{1+x}<1.1\iff x<1.1^2-1=0.21.$$
For $-1\le x\le0$,
$$\sqrt{1+x}>0.9\iff x>0.9^2-1=-0.19.$$
The largest open interval on which $|\sqrt{1+x}-1|<0.1$ holds is therefore
$$(-0.19,0.21).$$
